# How can I get count of active Users from google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I want just to get count of active users and display it on my own dashboard, but I cant find any way how to do this.

I found https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/reference/data/realtime/get

but I need some viewId and I use web+app type for my analytics so I dont have this viewId.

How can I access to this number ? How can I just get count of active users that I see on dashboard.

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no reporting API for App+Web, it's in beta so you should use this new property in parallel with the known one.

However, you can configure a BigQuery Export and link that dataset to Data Studio: https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/enable-bigquery-export-google-analytics-app-web/

Comment: Yes, but data in bigguery exports with delay, but I need current active users count as I can see on dashboard when I open it.

Comment: What about StreamView on firebase, can I get info from it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the number of active users in the last 30 minutes, there is a REST API for that. Specifically, there is a *Realtime* API for GA4 Properties.

This developer site provides an introduction to creating a realtime report: https://developers.google.com/analytics/trusted-testing/analytics-data/realtime-basics. If you are interested in Active Users counts for your app or website, you can send API requests with just the metric "Active Users". For example, send the following request:

```
POST https://analyticsdata.googleapis.com/v1alpha/properties/YOUR_PROPERTY_ID:runRealtimeReport
{
  "metrics": [{ "name": "activeUsers" }]
}
```

There is a separate Realtime rest API for views; as you linked, https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/reference/data/realtime/get. GA4 Properties do not have views.