# How to get count of active users grouped by version? (from Firebase using BigQuery)

Tags: sql, firebase, google-bigquery, google-analytics

#### Problem description

I'm trying to get the information of how many active users I have in my app separated by the 2 or 3 latest versions of the app.

I've read some documentations and other stack questions but none of them was solving my problem (and some others had outdated solutions).

#### Examples of solutions I tried:

- https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9037342?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article (**N-day active users** - This solution is probably the best, but even changing the dataset name correctly and removing the `_TABLE_SUFFIX` conditions it kept returning me a single column n_day_active_users_count = 0 )
- https://gist.github.com/sbrissenden/cab9bd3a043f1879ded605cba5005457
  (this is not returning any values for me, didn't understand why)
- [How can I get count of active Users from google analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62157823/how-can-i-get-count-of-active-users-from-google-analytics) (this is not a good fit because the other part of my job is already done and generating charts on Data Studio, so using REST API would be harder to join my two solutions - one from BigQuery and other from REST API)
- [Discrepancies on "active users metric" between Firebase Analytics dashboard and BigQuery export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40853347/discrepancies-on-active-users-metric-between-firebase-analytics-dashboard-and?rq=1) (this one uses outdated variables)

### So, I started to write the solution out of my head, and this is what I get so far:

```sql
SELECT 
  user_pseudo_id,
  app_info.version,
  ROUND(COUNT(DISTINCT user_pseudo_id) OVER (PARTITION BY app_info.version) / SUM(COUNT(DISTINCT user_pseudo_id)) OVER (), 3) AS adoption
FROM `projet-table.events_*`
WHERE platform = 'ANDROID'
GROUP BY app_info.version, user_pseudo_id
ORDER BY app_info.version
```

[image: screenshot of code and results of my query]

### Conclusions

- I'm not sure if my logic is correct, but I think I can use `user_pseudo_id` to calculate it, right? The general idea is: user_of_X_version/users_of_all_versions.
  (And the results are kinda close to the ones showing at Google Analytics web platform - I believe the difference is due to the date that I turned on the BigQuery  integration. But.... **I'd like some confirmation on that: if my logic is correct**).
- The biggest problem in my code now is that I cannot write it without grouping by `user_pseudo_id` (Because when I don't BigQuery says: "*SELECT list expression references column
  user_pseudo_id which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [2:3]*") and that's why I have duplicated rows in the query result
- Also, about the first link of examples... Is there any possibility of a record with engagement_time_msec param with value < 0? If not, why is that condition in the where clause?

Comment: Hi Thur did you ever end up getting the result you were looking for?

Comment: Actually I didn't get all the answers, but got quite close results to the ones shown in Google Analytics platform. I have crash-free values and adoption split by version.

(sorry for the delay on answering, I'll share my query as soon as I get home tonight)